# How to Populate Multidimensional Array in Excel Macro using For Each Loop With Formula?

Tags: vba, excel

I want to populate Array in VBA , using for each-loop but unable to do that

```
Dim MyArray() As Variant
Dim RowCounter As Integer
Dim ColCounter As Integer
Dim rCell As Range
Dim rRng As Range
Set rRng = Sheet1.Range("B10:Z97")
RowCounter = 0
ColCounter = 0
ReDim MyArray(rRng.Rows.Count, rRng.Columns.Count)  'Answer by @varocarbas
For Each rCol In rRng.Columns
   For Each rCell In rCol.Rows
    If IsNumeric(rCell.Value) And (Not (IsEmpty(rCell.Value))) And (Len(rCell.Value) <> 0) Then
         'ReDim Preserve MyArray(RowCounter, ColCounter) -- Old Logic which cause Error
         MyArray(RowCounter, ColCounter) = rCell.Value
         RowCounter = RowCounter + 1
    Else
        'Debug.Print rCell.Value & " is not an Integer" & vbNewLine
    End If
  Next rCell
  ColCounter = ColCounter + 1
  RowCounter = 0
Next rCol
```

But `ReDim Preserve MyArray(RowCounter, ColCounter)` in this line I got **subscript error** , when `ReDim Preserve MyArray(1, 0)`

I want to read the value from excel sheet populate the array then do some calculation and update the value of Last Cell of the each Column in Excel from by Calculate Value of the Excel.

**Update in code**

```
Function RunSquareOfVariance(temperature As Integer, cellValue As Variant) As Double
         RunSquareOfVariance = "=IF((" & temperature + cellValue & ")<0,0,(" & temperature + cellValue & "))*IF((" & temperature + cellValue & ")<0,0,(" & temperature + cellValue & "))"
End Function
```

If **within the code** I change the bellow line

`MyArray(RowCounter, ColCounter) = RunSquareOfVariance(StantardTemperature, rCell.Value)`

Now within **MyArray(0,0)** Value store As `=IF((-16.8)<0,0,(-16.8))*IF((-16.8)<0,0,(-16.8))`

But I want to store the value of the formula Withing `MyArray(0,0) = ValueOftheFormula`

Comment: Why not redim just once at the top? ReDim MyArray(rRng.Columns.Count, rRng.Rows.Count)

Comment: @varocarbas : Yes I did that, I found that area.

Comment: You can also use `myArray = Range("B10:Z97")` ! Fastest.

Comment: @iDevlop : Yes I can do that, thanks, **Correction:**  `myarray = Range("B10:Z97").Value`. I update my code, would you please check. And help me out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK Problem solved

```
MyArray(RowCounter, ColCounter) = Application.Evaluate
        (
          RunSquareOfVariance(StantardTemperature, rCell.Value)
        )
```

Comment: FYI, you can also write that this way:
`MyArray(RowCounter, ColCounter) = [RunSquareOfVariance(StantardTemperature, rCell.Value]`

Comment: @iDevlop : It is throwing Run-time Error - '13' (Type mismatch) -- in Excel 2007

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can remember you can change size ONLY of the last array dimension.

To be sure I've just checked and it's true. According to MSDN:

> If you use the Preserve keyword, you can resize only the last array
>   dimension and you can't change the number of dimensions at all.

I don't know the ultimate goal of your sub therefore is difficult to suggest any changes. However, you could consider working with array of arrays. Syntax of such solution works as follows:

```
Dim arrA() As Variant
Dim arrB() As Variant
...
ReDim Preserve arrA(RowCounter)
ReDim Preserve arrB(ColCounter)
...
arrA(RowCounter) = x
arrB(ColCounter) = y
...
Dim arrAB
arrAB = Array(arrA, arrB)
...
'to get elements of array you need to call it in this way:
arrAB(0)(RowCounter) >> to get x
arrAB(1)(ColCounter) >> to get y
```

There are some disadvantages of such solution but could be useful in other situation.

Comment: You can `Transpose` the array to achieve this.

Comment: @brettdj, your comments was a bit unclear but I made some experiments and I could say....good to know :)

Answer (score 0):

You could do simply:

```
Dim rng As Range
Dim myArray() As Variant
Set rRng =  Sheet1.Range("B10:Z97")
myArray = rRng.Value
```

You will also need to `For Each rCell In rRng.Rows` instead of `For Each rCell In rCol.Rows`.  Otherwise, like Kaz says, you can only resize the last dimension of an array.

Answer (score 0):

I can see you have found a solution for your issue. For future reference, I would like to add an alternative way of going about this.
In particular, I agree with @DavidZemens ’s approach on copying the range values to a variant array directly. It is a very elegant, simple and efficient solution. The only tricky part is when there are empty or non-numeric cells in the range you are looking, and you do not want to insert these values. A modification of David’s approach would work in case some of the values you are copying are not numbers.

```
Sub CopyNumbersToArray()
Dim var As Variant, rng As Range
' Grab the numeric values of the range only. Checking if cell is empty or
' if it has a positive length is not needed
Set rng = Range("B3:K3").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlNumbers)
' Copy the numbers. Note that var=rng.value will not work if rng is not contiguous
rng.Copy
' Paste the numbers temporarily to a range that you do not use
Range("A10000").Resize(1, rng.Count).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
' Set rng object to point to that range
Set rng = Range(Cells(10000, 1), Cells(10000, rng.Count))
' Store the values that you need in a variant array
var = rng.Value
' Clear the contents of the temporary range
rng.ClearContents
End Sub
```

For more than 2 dimensions, jagged arrays is probably a good way to go (as suggested by @KazJaw)

Comment: Nice Explanation, but I did it in different way, Thanks